# how to toggle on and off

Tags: javascript, html

I was testing some JS and wanted to know how I can toggle on the background color change and then toggle off color change back to normal.

Thanks!

```js
function myFunk() {
  var y = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    y[2].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<button onclick="myFunk()">push me</button>
```

Comment: do you want to have only one header with a decent color? please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments inline below:

```js
// Do your event binding in JavaScript, not HTML
document.querySelector("button[type='button']").addEventListener("click", myFunk);

function myFunk(){
  var y = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

  // No need for a loop if you are just targeting specific elements
  // Use the .toggle() method of the .classList property and work
  // with pre-made classes instead of inline styles
  y[1].classList.toggle("red");
  y[2].classList.toggle("blue");

}
```

```css
.blue { background-color:blue; }
.red { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<button type="button">push me</button>
```

Comment: @cyberAnn You're welcome. Please consider marking this as "the" answer by clicking the arrow at the top-left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective solution is simply `toggle` a class. Also if you are referring to the object in an array manually, you don't need the loop

```js
function myFunk(){
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
    y[1].classList.toggle("red");
    y[2].classList.toggle("blue");
}
```

```css
.red{background-color:red;}
.blue{background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<html>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<button onclick="myFunk()">push me</button>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the index for the red color and replace other colors with blue.

This approach uses a global variable `index` which stores the index of the actual highlighted element.

All elements are visited and if the index of the active index is equal to the element with the same index, the color changes to red, all other elements gets blue.

At the end, the index is incremented and adjusted to prevent an index out of range for the elements.

```js
function toggle() {
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].style.backgroundColor = i === index ? "red" : "blue";
    }
    index++;
    index %= y.length;
}

var index = 0;
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h1>hello</h1>
<button onclick="toggle()">push me</button>
```

Comment: hi Nina, this is a really creative way of changing colors on the index.... can you explain the code to me a bit more so I understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(element => element.classList.toggle('highlight'))
```

1) Find all element by some attribute (e.g. 'h2')
2) Iterate over all found elements
3) Assign class `highlight` if it was not assigned yet
4) Done

In case I want to have a toggle effect, you can put it inside the function and call it again.

```
const toggle = (target, className) => {
  document.querySelectorAll(target).forEach(element => element.classList.toggle(className))
}

toggle('h2', 'highlight');
toggle('h2', 'highlight');
```

where `highlight` is

```
.highlight {
  background: red;
}
```